# How to call Jenkins API with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jenkins

Could you tell me how to call Jenkins API with JavaScript?

I have the code in Python:

```
import requests

build = requests.post("http://YOUR_JENKINS_USER_ID:YOUR_API_TOKEN@YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JENKINS_JOB/build?token=TokenName")
```

and in Python it works perfectly fine, could you please tell me how to do the same in JavaScript?

Comment: Are you talking about browser Javascript ? Or Node.js ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Frontend

If you want to make a call from the frontend application the code would look like following:

```js
async function makeRequest() {
    const url = "http://YOUR_JENKINS_USER_ID:YOUR_API_TOKEN@YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JENKINS_JOB/build?token=TokenName"

    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    });
    const resJson = await res.json();

    return resJson;
}
```

#### Node.js Application

If you want to make request from `Node.js` application first you have to install `node-fetch` using following command:

```sh
npm install node-fetch
```

Then your code would look like following:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function makeRequest() {
    const url = "http://YOUR_JENKINS_USER_ID:YOUR_API_TOKEN@YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job/YOUR_JENKINS_JOB/build?token=TokenName"

    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    });
    const resJson = await res.json();

    return resJson;
}
```